# Usb sound device to 3.5mm output real time

Tags: audio, output

I have a raspberry with a usb mic. I want to stream realtime the mic input to the 3.5mm output.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think it is possible, for example you can use [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) file:

```
~$ mkfifo /tmp/input.audio.fifo
```

Write a python programm like this (warning, this script record only 60sec of audio, you can adjust this):
[Python code REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344649/reading-input-sound-signal-using-python).

To install: python -m pip install pyaudio

```
    """PyAudio example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 60
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "/tmp/input.audio.fifo"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

And configure the RPi audio for Jack output not HDMI then use aplay for reading the fifo file for getting your audio output (in another terminal), :

```
~$ aplay /tmp/input.audio.fifo
```

let me know if it works because I have not tried. Good luck.

Steps:

1. Create FIFO file
2. Configure python script audio file output
   with your FIFO file and run the python script. (audio input) or I think you can use `arecord /tmp/input.audio.fifo` instance of the python script.
3. Use an audio player for reading the FIFO file. (audio output)

Comment: You can probably also use `arecord` instance of the python program : `mkfifo /tmp/input.audio.fifo` then`arecord - | tee /tmp/input.audio.fifo` (audio INPUT) and get the output in another terminal : `aplay /tmp/input.audio.fifo` (audio OUTPUT)