# How do I make my record player play through speakers with my raspberry pi b+ v1.2?

Tags: audio

I recently got a record player, the AT-LP60-USB from Audio-Technica, and I want to make it play through a set of digital speakers I have. The turntable acts as an audio USB input. Basically, I need to be able to take a USB audio input and output its sound through the 3.5mm jack on my pi. I also need to be able to simply plug it in and have it work with no setup. How would I go about making this?

Comment: You can use `udev` for detecting some USB hot-plug and automatically run the commands (commands for creating fifo file and run arecord and aplay) , use `system unit file` at the RPi startup... You can check my answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102246/usb-sound-device-to-3-5mm-output-real-time/102252#102252).

Comment: is there any simpler solution? really all I need it to do is play the audio to the desktop then send it to the speakers.

Comment: No, sorry not to my knowledge. The system use USB for the Audio INPUT in your case , by defaut the system not understand what do you want to do and not redirect any audio on another interface. Maybe some tricks exists on the hardware part for this but I have never see that.